# Nonlinear contraction on Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $C\subset H$ be a nonempty closed convex subset of a Hilbert space $H$ and let $T:C\rightarrow C$ be a nonlinear contraction; i.e.
$$|Tu-Tv|\leq|u-v|\quad\forall u,v\in C.$$
Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence in $C$ s.t. $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ weakly and $(u_n-T u_n)\rightarrow f$ strongly. Then I am asked to prove that $u-Tu=f$ and furthermore if $C$ is bounded and $T(C)\subset C$, then $T$ has a fixed point.
The hint for the first part is the inequality
$$((u-Tu)-(v-Tv),u-v)\geq0\forall u,v$$ and the hint for the second is to consider $T_\varepsilon u=(1-\varepsilon)Tu+\varepsilon a$ with $a\in C$ fixed and $\varepsilon>0,\varepsilon\rightarrow0$.

My idea for the first part was to use the inequality to obtain
$$(Tu-Tv,u-v)\leq(u-v,u-v),$$
and then I need to show
$$((u-Tu)-f,(u-Tu)-f)=0.$$
I may replace $f$ by $u_n-Tu_n$ by the strong convergence and then use weak convergence $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ to strip the terms not indexed by $n$ from the equation. I may then use 'the inequality' above to arrive at
$$((u-Tu)-(u-u_n),(u-Tu)-(u-u_n))\leq(u-u_n,Tu_n-u_n)$$
but I have no reason to conclude that this goes to $0$. :(

Comment: There may be an issue with your problem statement.  The identity qualifies as a contraction since you have $\le$.  How then can you prove that $C$ is bounded?  Perhaps you mean **if** $C$ is bounded **then** $T$ has a fixed point?  Also you've written $T:C\to C$, from which it would seem to follow immediately that $T(C)\subset C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your last inequality is correct (haven't checked that), then the RHS goes to $0$:
$$(u-u_n,Tu_n-u_n)=(u-u_n,Tu_n-u_n+f-f)=(u-u_n,-f)+(u-u_n,Tu_n-u_n+f)=(u-u_n,-f)+(u,Tu_n-u_n+f)-(u_n,Tu_n-u_n+f)$$
Here all terms tend to $0$: the first one, because $u-u_n\rightharpoonup 0$, the second because $Tu_n-u_n+f\to 0$, and the third, because $\|u_n\|$ is bounded by, say $M$, as a weakly convergent sequence and therefore $|(u_n,Tu_n-u_n+f)|\leq M\|Tu_n-u_n+f\|\to 0$

Comment: Thank you – and how to conclude that $T$ has a fixed point, under the additional conditions?

Comment: What does it mean "and furthermore $C$ is bounded and $T(C)\subset C$, then $T$ has a fixed point." ? It is not clear what you mean here.

Comment: $C$ is bounded means $\exists M>0 : \forall c\in C, \|c\|\leqq M$. $T(C)\subset C$ means $\forall c\in C, Tc\in C$. $T$ has a fixed point means $Tc=c$.

Comment: I meant if it means: "and furthermore if $C$ is bounded and $T(C)\subset C$, then prove that $T$ has a fixed point "

Comment: Yes, nevermind, I see how the argument goes. If $C$ is bounded then it is weakly compact hence the $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ at least along a subsequence, and then $u_n-Tu_n\rightarrow 0$. So, no problem. Thanks.